# Match 2 columns (First and last names) on two excel worksheet and copy data

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I searched stack overflow for similar question and here is the code that i found (modified slightly) and below code matches 1 column.

Require to match 2 columns( first and last name) in both sheets instead of 1 column first name and in 4.mobile sheet to start from row 18 and ignore any matched names above row 18

[image]

[image]

```
Sub CopyBasedonSheet1()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Sheet4LastRow = Worksheets("4. Mobile").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sheet7LastRow = Worksheets("Contacts").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To Sheet4LastRow
        For i = 1 To sheet7LastRow
            If Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 4).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 1).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 3).Value
                Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 3).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 4).Value
                Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 6).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 5).Value
                Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 7).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 6).Value
                Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 8).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 7).Value

            Else
            End If
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do, what have you done, what has happened?

Comment: Match 2 columns from 2 different sheets and extract specific data into sheet 1. Above code matches 1 column.

Comment: You should be able to do this via `sumproduct` as demonstrated by @scottcraner [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125502/if-cell-in-column-partially-contains-text-in-another-column/37125607#37125607).

Comment: @findwindow I would use INDEX/MATCH in this case because some of the returned is text.  Also I would only use formula if the datasets are relatively small; <1000, or the fact that this would require an array formula it would bog down the calc times.

Comment: Just kidding. Ignore me XD

Answer (score 0):

If I understand all you need to do is add an `And` in your If:

```
Sub CopyBasedonSheet1()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Sheet4LastRow = Worksheets("4. Mobile").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sheet7LastRow = Worksheets("Contacts").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To Sheet4LastRow
        For i = 1 To sheet7LastRow
            If Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 4).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 1).Value _
                And Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 5).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 2).Value Then
                Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 1).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 3).Value
                Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 3).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 4).Value
                Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 6).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 5).Value
                Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 7).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 6).Value
                Worksheets("4. Mobile").Cells(j, 8).Value = Worksheets("Contacts").Cells(i, 7).Value

            Else
            End If
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked thanks....How do i fill in data back into Contact sheet if any data missing( ex. phone number missing) and i enter it manually and has to be filled into main contact sheet. And if no match of first and last name new record to be inserted into contact sheet

Comment: You would need another sub that does what this one does but backwards.  that is a new question and try it on your own before simply asking a new question.  As this answered your current question please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Sure..Will open new sub..Tried and gauging internet to reverse it. One more query for same thread, How do i make change In 4.mobile sheet to start from row 18 and ignore any matched names above row 18.